# WP8 - RateMyApp "addon" exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, stack-trace, inner-exception

I found out this nice addon by nokia, https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app

I followed their guide to implement it in my app, that can be downloaded here https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app/blob/master/Doc/RateMyAppGuide.pdf?raw=true

Nothing difficult in that guide, by the way, I just needed to install an addon into my project and to add 2 lines of code,

```
xmlns:rma="clr-namespace:RateMyApp.Controls;assembly=RateMyApp"
```

and

```
<rma:FeedbackOverlay x:Name="FeedbackOverlay" Grid.RowSpan="2" FeedbackTo="me@test.com" ApplicationName="MyApp" CompanyName="MyCompany"/>
```

I actually did everything not encountering any issue at all. As I tried to edit the XAML code of the rma:FeedbackOverlay object, the "GUI" window (the one near the XAML project) throw this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: The property "FeedbackOverlay.Message" does not expose a get method.
InnerException: None
(there is also a StackTrace that I am not able to read, but I can provide it if anyone can read that for me)
```

I tried deploying the app on my device, and it actually runs fine, making the extension work as it is meant to. Yet, I am worried about that exception. Do I have reason to be? How may I solve that? Thanks in advance!

(yeah, I tried rebooting pc, restarting IDE, nothing worked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked the code of [this addon](https://github.com/nokia-developer/rate-my-app/tree/5f2249000e7f4eb49f76ed0eb09357ece9f5c018). And if you open there FeedbackOverlay.xaml.cs you will find that Message property lacks get accessor:

```
public string Message
{
   // get { //something } - is not here
   set
   {
      // some code
   }
}
```

But in this case (as this property is used only to define a message - not get it) the get accessor isn't needed. So the exception you get is probably only from Visual Studio and it informs that there can be a problem if you had tried to get value of Message.
So unless you try to get the value of Message - for example:

```
string myMessage = FeedbackOverlay.Message;
```

there should be no problem (VS should also mark this code above). There can be also a problem if you try to get this value in xaml (for example using Binding).
I also think that it would be nice if you had informed the developer (you will probably find his e-mail easily on Github or somewhere in the project) that you encountered such an issue.

Hope this helps.